# How to insert records in Spring batch List<DTO> type

Tags: java, mysql, list, spring-boot, spring-batch

I want to read data from same row in excel and insert each record as new record into a mysql table using spring batch.

```
@Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<List<student>> writer(DataSource dataSource4) {
        return new JdbcBatchItemWriterBuilder<List<student>>()
           .itemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<List<student>>())
           .sql("INSERT INTO students ( name,class,rank,status) VALUES (:Name,:Class,:Rank,'A')")
           .dataSource(dataSource4)
           .build();
```

but its showing the following error

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter 'Name': Invalid property 'Name' of bean class [java.util.ArrayList]: Bean property 'Name' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

Is this possible my requirement possible in spring batch ? if yes can anyone explain?

Thanks!!

Comment: There is a problem in the design of your "item" and itemWriter. The writer is accepting a `List<student>` while the SQL is for inserting a single student. How would you do that without Spring Batch? I guess your `itemSqlParameterSourceProvider` should be set to `new BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Student>()` (without the List<>).

Comment: Okay but how to insert List<student> ??

Comment: Write the query to insert a single item, and Spring Batch will iterate over the list of students and insert them in batches.